# How to access data from many tables in src blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In my org document, I have several tables named (with `#+name:`) t1, t2, etc. I want to pass all of the tables to some lisp code. This is what I have so far:

```
#+name: process-tables
#+header: :var t1=t1 t2=t2 t3=t3 t4=t4 t5=t5 t6=t6 t7=t7 t8=t8 t9=t9 t10=t10 t11=t11 t12=t12 t13=t13 t14=t14
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
    (process (append t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 t11 t12 t13 t14))
#+END_SRC
```

This seems very clumsy. Is there a better way? I do not want to merge the tables in the org document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `org-table-map-tables` and `org-table-to-lisp` functions to create a list of all tables in the buffer. This avoids having to invoke table names individually.

```
(defun org-tables-to-list ()
  (let (tbls)
    (org-table-map-tables
     (lambda ()
       (push (org-table-to-lisp) tbls))
     t)
    (apply #'append (nreverse tbls))))
```

For example:

```
#+name: t1
| 0 | 1 |

#+name: t2
| 2 | 3 |

#+name: process-tables
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value verbatim
(org-tables-to-list)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: process-tables
: (("0" "1") ("2" "3"))
```